# invalid group specification - None of the groups defined by center is a control

Tags: stata

Here I am trying to do the DID model in Stata using the following dataset, However the .didregress command gives me the following error: **invalid group specification - None of the groups defined by center is a control.**
Does anyone know what's the cause of this problem?
The dataset looks like:
[image]

and here is my command and error:
[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about the OP's dataset and whether it suits a particular analysis.

Comment: Can you show the result of `tab center Week, m`. I do not know this specific command but if seems to be a command for diff-in-diff regressions and it seems as if you do not have obs in each combination of `center` and `Week`

Comment: Looks like you have no 0's in variable `center`?